# PhpStorm + Mantis

Tags: phpstorm

Кто сталкивался с этой связкой и как оно работает?

Есть установленный мантис и phpstorm, в шторме подключен мантис.

как передавать баги в мантис? Или шторм как-то сам их передает при каких-то условиях?

Comment: Пробовал, потратил 2 часа, но так и не завел - пишет, что ароде как коннектится к баг-трекеру, но увы таски так и не показал))))

Comment: А как ты его заставил коннектиться? Какой url  прописал?
А той только ошибки выдает при попытке подключения... ((

Comment: Да с коннектом все нормально. На локальном сервере стоит мантис по адресу http://mantis.loc в программе этот url и прописан. Коннект то нормальный.
Непонятно из шторма в мантис писать, т.к. шторм видит какие-то задачи но сам писать их по видимому не умеет.